# Sporadic segfault in c++ python extension

Tags: c++, python, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access, python-extensions

I have a python object which accesses and downloads some text via HTTP.
I'm running this python object, and processing that text, using a c++ code.
I.e.

```
/* CPPCode.cxx */
int main(...) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numURLs; i++) {
        // Python method returns a string
        PyObject *pyValue = PyObject_CallMethod(pyObjectInstance, pyFunctionName, par1, par2....);
        string valString = PyString_AsString(pHistValue);   
        // ... process string ... 
    }
} 

/* PyObject.py */
class PyClass:
    def PyFunction(...):
        try: urlSock = urllib.urlopen(urlName)
        except ...

        while(...) :
             dataStr = urlSock.readline()
             # do some basic string processing....

        return dataStr
```

Most URLs work fine---the c++ code gets the proper string, I can process it, all is happy and well.  A few particular URLs which look (basically) the same as the others on a browser, lead to a segfault in the PyString_AsString() method:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00000000000000b2
0x000000010007716d in PyString_AsString ()
```

If I print out the string that should be returned by the python method ('dataStr' in the pseudo-code above), it looks fine!  I have no idea what could be causing this problem---any tips on how to procede would be appreciated!
Thanks

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

SOLUTION:

The template code I was using had a call to

```
Py_DECREF(pyValue)
```

before I called

```
PyString_AsString(pyValue)
```

Why it was being deallocated for certain particular function calls, I have no idea.  As 'Gecco' says in the comments below,

'PyString_AsString documentation says: "The pointer refers to the internal buffer of string, not a copy. The data must not be modified in any way, unless the string was just created using PyString_FromStringAndSize(NULL, size). It must not be deallocated." '

Comment: And what is this mystery URL?

Comment: http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/PAFM/2012/01/05/DailyHistory.html?HideSpecis=0&format=1

Comment: unexplicable segfault: This is quite often due to some memory-allocation errors. Check your _entire_ code to ensure you correctly allocate and free used memory...

Comment: `PyString_AsString` documentation says: "The pointer refers to the internal buffer of string, not a copy. The data must not be modified in any way, unless the string was just created using PyString_FromStringAndSize(NULL, size). **It must not be deallocated**." _Please ensure you do not deallocate this buffer._

Comment: @gecco That was my first thought, but I'm not using *any* dynamically allocated memory; and because the segfault is happening for the same URL every time, regardless of how many I examine before or after, it seems there might be another issue.

I'm not manually allocating or deallocating any memory.

Comment: `address: 0x00000000000000b2` looks like data rather than a pointer.  Check the pointer being passed into PyString_AsString.

Comment: @gecco you were right, there was a Py_DECREF(pyValue) stuck in there from the template code that I originally copied.
Removing it fixed the problem!  Thanks!

Comment: @zhermes I posted my comment as an answer in case you want to reward me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyString_AsString` documentation says: "The pointer refers to the internal buffer of string, not a copy. The data must not be modified in any way, unless the string was just created using PyString_FromStringAndSize(NULL, size). **It must not be deallocated**."

*Please ensure you do not deallocate this buffer*

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your C code with the -g debug flag (in GCC at least) then you can run your python code using the gnu debugger gdb:

```
$ gdb /path/to/python/compiled/against 
... blah ...
(gdb) run PyObject.py
```

and you should catch your segfault.

Comment: Here is my full backtrace from GDB

`code`
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff80237c00 in strlen ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff80237c00 in strlen ()
#1  0x0000000100088e1e in PyString_FromFormatV ()
#2  0x00000001000d3fdc in PyErr_Format ()
#3  0x000000010008510a in PyString_AsStringAndSize ()
#4  0x0000000100085183 in PyString_AsString ()
#5  0x000000010000f6f3 in callPythonWHistoryMethod () at stl_vector.h:137
#6  0x0000000100010555 in main () at stl_vector.h:137

Comment: So you can now prod the code to see what was breaking everything - for example, what is "pHistValue" : try "(gdb) print pHistValue" and see if it is what you expected

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the Py_DECREF is somehow getting a NULL value.

Comment: My understanding is that once the references to an object are zero, it is deallocated (like in cocoa, e.g.).

Comment: Yes, when it reaches zero it will deallocate.  Good catch, I will fix it.